# Felix: deployed bundle starts twice

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, sling

I'm deploying with Maven (but same issue with Felix web console) and the maven-sling-plugin and I see it starts twice:

```
*INFO* [qtp1462409406-40] logs/access.log 127.0.0.1 - admin 25/Feb/2016:11:18:31 +0100 "POST /dev/system/console/install HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1"
*INFO* [Background Install /var/folders/v0/gh9_k3ld5vx43sn057mg6h3c0000gn/T/install2994913564032148892.tmp] com.as.test.content BundleEvent INSTALLED
*INFO* [Background Install /var/folders/v0/gh9_k3ld5vx43sn057mg6h3c0000gn/T/install2994913564032148892.tmp] com.as.test.content BundleEvent RESOLVED
*INFO* [Background Install /var/folders/v0/gh9_k3ld5vx43sn057mg6h3c0000gn/T/install2994913564032148892.tmp] com.as.test.content BundleEvent STARTING
*INFO* [Background Install /var/folders/v0/gh9_k3ld5vx43sn057mg6h3c0000gn/T/install2994913564032148892.tmp] com.as.test.content BundleEvent STARTED
*INFO* [Background Install /var/folders/v0/gh9_k3ld5vx43sn057mg6h3c0000gn/T/install2994913564032148892.tmp] com.as.test.content Service [com.as.test.jcr.service.NodeFinderImpl,374] ServiceEvent REGISTERED
*INFO* [Background Install /var/folders/v0/gh9_k3ld5vx43sn057mg6h3c0000gn/T/install2994913564032148892.tmp] com.as.test.content Service [com.as.test.jcr.service.NodeSorterImpl,375] ServiceEvent REGISTERED
*INFO* [Background Install /var/folders/v0/gh9_k3ld5vx43sn057mg6h3c0000gn/T/install2994913564032148892.tmp] com.as.test.content Service [com.as.test.jcr.service.UserProcessorImpl,376] ServiceEvent REGISTERED

====> Starts executing code: creates users, sets permissions and sort nodes with the JCR API
[...]
*ERROR* [pool-7-thread-1] com.as.test.content [com.as.test.jcr.service.ContentInitializerImpl(173)] Failed creating the component instance; see log for reason
*INFO* [FelixFrameworkWiring] com.as.test.content BundleEvent STOPPING
*INFO* [FelixFrameworkWiring] com.as.test.content Service [com.as.test.jcr.service.ContentInitializerImpl,383] ServiceEvent UNREGISTERING
*INFO* [FelixFrameworkWiring] com.as.test.content Service [com.as.test.jcr.service.NodeSorterImpl,375] ServiceEvent UNREGISTERING
*INFO* [FelixFrameworkWiring] com.as.test.content Service [com.as.test.jcr.service.UserProcessorImpl,376] ServiceEvent UNREGISTERING
*INFO* [FelixFrameworkWiring] com.as.test.content Service [com.as.test.jcr.service.NodeFinderImpl,374] ServiceEvent UNREGISTERING
*INFO* [FelixFrameworkWiring] com.as.test.content BundleEvent STOPPED
*INFO* [FelixFrameworkWiring] com.as.test.content BundleEvent UNRESOLVED
*INFO* [FelixFrameworkWiring] com.as.test.content BundleEvent RESOLVED
*INFO* [FelixFrameworkWiring] com.as.test.content BundleEvent STARTING
*INFO* [FelixFrameworkWiring] org.apache.sling.jcr.contentloader.internal.Loader Content of bundle already loaded com.as.test.content.
*INFO* [FelixFrameworkWiring] com.as.test.content BundleEvent STARTED
*INFO* [FelixFrameworkWiring] com.as.test.content Service [com.as.test.jcr.service.NodeFinderImpl,384] ServiceEvent REGISTERED
*INFO* [FelixFrameworkWiring] com.as.test.content Service [com.as.test.jcr.service.NodeSorterImpl,385] ServiceEvent REGISTERED
*INFO* [FelixFrameworkWiring] com.as.test.content Service [com.as.test.jcr.service.ContentInitializerImpl,387] ServiceEvent REGISTERED
*INFO* [FelixFrameworkWiring] com.as.test.jcr.service.ContentInitializerImpl Initializing Sling content
====> Starts (again) executing code: creates users, sets permissions and sort nodes with the JCR API
```

I'm executing some code on bundle's startup and it gets stopped in the middle of it, and then restarted, and I can't find why.

I've tried with Sling launchpad 7 and 8, respectively using org.apache.felix.framework 4.4.1 and 5.2.0

EDIT: stacktraces

```
1. Starts from background install
*INFO* [Background Install /var/folders/v0/gh9_k3ld5vx43sn057mg6h3c0000gn/T/install3836459285044407564.tmp] com.as.test.Activator   java.lang.Thread.getAllStackTraces(Thread.java:1640)
*INFO* [Background Install /var/folders/v0/gh9_k3ld5vx43sn057mg6h3c0000gn/T/install3836459285044407564.tmp] com.as.test.Activator   com.as.test.Activator.printStrackTraces(Activator.java:33)
*INFO* [Background Install /var/folders/v0/gh9_k3ld5vx43sn057mg6h3c0000gn/T/install3836459285044407564.tmp] com.as.test.Activator   com.as.test.Activator.start(Activator.java:23)
*INFO* [Background Install /var/folders/v0/gh9_k3ld5vx43sn057mg6h3c0000gn/T/install3836459285044407564.tmp] com.as.test.Activator   org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:645)
*INFO* [Background Install /var/folders/v0/gh9_k3ld5vx43sn057mg6h3c0000gn/T/install3836459285044407564.tmp] com.as.test.Activator   org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2154)
*INFO* [Background Install /var/folders/v0/gh9_k3ld5vx43sn057mg6h3c0000gn/T/install3836459285044407564.tmp] com.as.test.Activator   org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2072)
*INFO* [Background Install /var/folders/v0/gh9_k3ld5vx43sn057mg6h3c0000gn/T/install3836459285044407564.tmp] com.as.test.Activator   org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:976)
*INFO* [Background Install /var/folders/v0/gh9_k3ld5vx43sn057mg6h3c0000gn/T/install3836459285044407564.tmp] com.as.test.Activator   org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:963)
*INFO* [Background Install /var/folders/v0/gh9_k3ld5vx43sn057mg6h3c0000gn/T/install3836459285044407564.tmp] com.as.test.Activator   org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.core.InstallHelper.doRun(InstallHelper.java:67)
*INFO* [Background Install /var/folders/v0/gh9_k3ld5vx43sn057mg6h3c0000gn/T/install3836459285044407564.tmp] com.as.test.Activator   org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.core.BaseUpdateInstallHelper.doRun(    BaseUpdateInstallHelper.java:89)
*INFO* [Background Install /var/folders/v0/gh9_k3ld5vx43sn057mg6h3c0000gn/T/install3836459285044407564.tmp] com.as.test.Activator   org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.core.BaseUpdateInstallHelper.run(    BaseUpdateInstallHelper.java:121)

2. Stops from FelixFrameworkWiring
*INFO* [FelixFrameworkWiring] com.as.test.Activator THREAD: Thread[FelixFrameworkWiring,5,main]
*INFO* [FelixFrameworkWiring] com.as.test.Activator   java.lang.Thread.dumpThreads(Native Method)
*INFO* [FelixFrameworkWiring] com.as.test.Activator   java.lang.Thread.getAllStackTraces(Thread.java:1640)
*INFO* [FelixFrameworkWiring] com.as.test.Activator   com.as.test.Activator.printStrackTraces(Activator.java:33)
*INFO* [FelixFrameworkWiring] com.as.test.Activator   com.as.test.Activator.start(Activator.java:23)
*INFO* [FelixFrameworkWiring] com.as.test.Activator   org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:645)
*INFO* [FelixFrameworkWiring] com.as.test.Activator   org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2154)
*INFO* [FelixFrameworkWiring] com.as.test.Activator   org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2072)
*INFO* [FelixFrameworkWiring] com.as.test.Activator   org.apache.felix.framework.Felix$RefreshHelper.restart(Felix.java:4911)
*INFO* [FelixFrameworkWiring] com.as.test.Activator   org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.refreshPackages(Felix.java:4148)
*INFO* [FelixFrameworkWiring] com.as.test.Activator   org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkWiringImpl.run(FrameworkWiringImpl.java:178)
*INFO* [FelixFrameworkWiring] com.as.test.Activator   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

3. Restarts from FelixFrameworkWiring
*INFO* [FelixFrameworkWiring] com.as.test.Activator THREAD: Thread[FelixFrameworkWiring,5,main]
*INFO* [FelixFrameworkWiring] com.as.test.Activator   java.lang.Thread.dumpThreads(Native Method)
*INFO* [FelixFrameworkWiring] com.as.test.Activator   java.lang.Thread.getAllStackTraces(Thread.java:1640)
*INFO* [FelixFrameworkWiring] com.as.test.Activator   com.as.test.Activator.printStrackTraces(Activator.java:33)
*INFO* [FelixFrameworkWiring] com.as.test.Activator   com.as.test.Activator.start(Activator.java:23)
*INFO* [FelixFrameworkWiring] com.as.test.Activator   org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:645)
*INFO* [FelixFrameworkWiring] com.as.test.Activator   org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2154)
*INFO* [FelixFrameworkWiring] com.as.test.Activator   org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2072)
*INFO* [FelixFrameworkWiring] com.as.test.Activator   org.apache.felix.framework.Felix$RefreshHelper.restart(Felix.java:4911)
*INFO* [FelixFrameworkWiring] com.as.test.Activator   org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.refreshPackages(Felix.java:4148)
*INFO* [FelixFrameworkWiring] com.as.test.Activator   org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkWiringImpl.run(FrameworkWiringImpl.java:178)
```

Comment: If I were you, I would write a Bundle Activator, and simply print the stacktrace from the start and stop method to the console from these methods. From the stacktraces, you can find out what is happening. Might be some magical technology that does weaving, but other there can be other reasons, too.

Comment: I think your pom.xml has role in this, can you please check?

Comment: I'll try the Activator and print the stacktrace. What should I check in the pom?

Comment: I've added stacktraces from the activator to my question. I don't really know what to do with that, I see there is two processes involved, Background installed and FelixFrameworkWiring but I don't know why they both starts my bundle.

Comment: Guess that your bundle is first started, and then some bundles are removed/installed, and then refresh is called because your bundle is re-wired to other packages. It could be interesting what the difference in the wirings are (if there is any). I would write out the result of the following now in the activate function and see if there is any change: bundleContext.getBundle().adapt(BundleWiring.class).getRequiredWires(null);

Comment: Using your code it confirms that it's wired to another of my bundles, using it for an enum storing Sling resource types. However, I don't restart it, and it doesn't show in the logs that it's restarted.

Comment: I have moved the code (constants and enums) from my other bundle into this one but I still have ti same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The best is for your bundle to be prepared for such a situation. Many things can cause bundles to start multiple times, that shouldn't be an exceptional situation.

Comment: Thank you Bertrand for your input. I don't really know what to do for that because it restarts right in the middle of my code execution (usually settings permissions with the JCR API like said here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21380400/sling-initial-content-loading-how-to-set-access-permissions) so suddenly the reference to my node finder service is null, and I don't know what I should use to handle this situation.

Comment: I have added null checks each time I use a reference to an API (mostly Jackrabbit API) so it doesn't throw NullPointerException, and just restart without exceptions, but I'm wondering if you have to always do that when you use references, and if that's what you means by "be prepared for such a situation". I probably have to learn about OSGi :)

Comment: Are you seeing services that you get via @Reference becoming null? In theory this should not happen AFAIK, you component should be deactivated. If you can reduce your example to the simplest thing that fails we might be able to explain why.

Comment: Yes, I do getNullPointerException at some point when calling services got via @Reference. I've tried to create a small bundle to reproduce the behaviour but I've not been able to do it. Basically what i do in my real bundle is to look for page type resources, group them by their parent resource (i.e. a document) and then sort them on a property using the JCR API. During this, the bundle restarts and the service that I use to query the JCR becomes null while my code is still executing.

Comment: It might be interesting to add logging to your component's deactivate method (or add such a method if needed) to check if it is deactivated before the references become null. In theory it should, and that would be a way for you to detect that the component should stop doing whatever it does.